# How to sync vm time with host?

Tags: qemu

My **QEMU VMs** are drifting time from the hosts.

I am taking the roundabout way of reaching out to an **ntp** host on the network, but that seems a bit too excessive for something that could be resolved locally and I don't mean running **ntpd**.

The manpage for `qemu-ga` mentions time sync capabilities, but it's a very confusing manpage. It provides very little information besides listing the capabilities. I'm still clueless about how to use it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I was off thinking i needed `qemu-ga`. Just removed that package from my vms. solution is to simply sync with hardware clock, which for qemu, is hopefully always the host time.

`# hwclock --system` or `-s`